# CSV to Dynamo Bulk Load Remove Data If Already Exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have been using a Lambda to process a `.csv` file that is dropped into an S3 bucket. I'm using the base Lambda code as described in [this AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-bulk-csv-ingestion-to-amazon-dynamodb/) using boto3.

This method works really well for loading the data from a CSV but when I want to upload a new CSV file and I remove data that is previously there, the Lambda does not remove that data since this uses `batch_writer` and `put_item` so it will only update data with the same `PK` and create new items if they don't exist.

I'm trying to figure out a way to make sure that if data is removed from the CSV, the Lambda will remove that data from the DynamoDB database as well but I just can't get my head around how I would go about doing that with the current process.

Has anyone solved this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Load to a new table. That way it will hold only the data in the CSV file, none other. Delete the old table after the load to the new table completes. (It's nice that you avoid paying for any delete calls.)

Comment: Table is controlled by a CloudFormation template... I don't think it would be a good option to modify/drop and recreate it outside of that.

Comment: If it’s a transient table maybe don’t use CFN. Think of it like a temporary scratch table associated with one load action, not a long-existing table. Created by the load for the load. Accessing code can parameterize the latest load table to use. The alternative is a slow and costly item-by-item delete.